# The limit of a family of complex sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, exponentiation

I want to prove the following thing, 
$$c_j \to 0, \, a_j \to \infty, \text{ and } a_j c_j \to \lambda, \text{ then } (1 + c_j)^{a_j} \to e^\lambda$$
where $c_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is easy if $c_j \in \mathbb{R}$ since we can take logarithm for $(1 + c_j)^{a_j}$ and then continue. However, if $c_j \in \mathbb{C}$, there might need a different technique. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since $c_j \to 0$ it means $|c_j| < \frac{1}{2}$ say for $j \ge j_0$, hence you can take the principal logarithm of $1+c_j$ and do the same as in the real case

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, but could you elaborate on it a little bit more?

Comment: put an answer as asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex powers can be tricky but here we use the following two unambiguous definitions:

$e^{\lambda}=\exp \lambda=\sum_{n \ge 0}{\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}}$ for any complex $\lambda$

$\log (1+c)=\sum_{n \ge 1}{(-1)^{n-1}\frac{c^n}{n}}$ for any complex $|c| <1$,

so then we define $(1+c)^a=\exp(a\log (1+c))$ for any $|c| <1, a$ complex

With the above $\exp$ is an entire function (hence continuous) so if we have $|c_k| <1, a_k$ arbitrary, and $a_k\log(1+c_k) \to A$, then $(1+c_k)^{a_k} \to \exp(A)=e^A$.

In our case we definitely have $|c_k| <\frac{1}{2}<1, k \ge k_0$ since $c_k \to 0$, so we need to show $a_kc_k \to \lambda$ implies $a_k\log(1+c_k) \to \lambda$.

But $a_kc_k \to \lambda$ means $|a_kc_k| \le 2(|\lambda|+1), k \ge k_1$, hence taking $k \ge k_0+k_1$ so we also have $|c_k| <\frac{1}{2}$ we then get:

$|a_k\log(1+c_k) -\lambda| \le |a_kc_k-\lambda|+ |a_kc_k||c_k|\sum_{n \ge 2}{\frac {|c_k|^{n-2}}{n}} \le |a_kc_k-\lambda|+4|c_k|(|\lambda|+1)$ by the inequality above for $|a_kc_k|$ and estimating the sum by the geometric one $\sum_{n \ge 2}{|c_k|^{n-2}} \le 2$.

Since $a_kc_k \to \lambda, c_k \to 0$ we are done!

Comment: Wow, thank you soooo much for your detail answer!! One question about the complex exponential. Is $z^c = \exp(c \log z)$ the usual definition, even just when $z\neq 0$, not only $\vert z \vert < 2$?

Comment: first of all the above requires $|z-1| <1$ not $|z|<2$; second, one can define the principal branch of the logarithm when $z \ne -x, x \ge 0$ real, so one can define $z^c$ that way for all such $z$; more generally one can have a branch of the logarithm that contains negatives (avoiding something else on a ray through the origin like positives or negative imaginaries) and define $z^c$ for nonzero $z$; the issues come when doing stuff with that as one has to be really careful about how $\log$ is defined; the case $|z-1|<1$ is simplest as we have a straightforward Taylor series that is nice

Answer (score -2):

Following basic (complex or real) limits:

$$(1 + c_j)^{a_j}=\left((1+c_j)^{1/c_j}\right)^{a_jc_j}\xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{}e^\lambda\;.$$

since $\; (1+c_j)^{1/c_j}\xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{} e\;$